# Handlebars, how to create layout for sub page using Node and express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm currently working on a simple CMS. I have some basic layout set up for each page like that:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

I have some pages and I would like to setup sublayout for those pages.
For example.
Each page need to have root layout but gallery/all, gallery/new etc. need its own sublayout. How can I do it?

solution :

I found a solution for this. Instead of using layout use handlebar partials

Answer (score 0):

You can use other layout: 'gallery_all_layout' in router:

```
res.render('gallery/all', {
    pageTitle: 'Gallery List',
    layout: 'gallery_all_layout'; //place it the same folder defaultLayout 'layout'
    ...
});
```